# Show there exists an invariant subspace $W\subseteq \mathbb R^n$..

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be an orthogonal operator in $\mathbb R^n$. How can I show there exists in invariant subspace $W\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $\textrm{dim}(W)=1$ or $\textrm{dim}(W)=2$? There was a hint for this problem: Consider $T+T^*$.. Any help will be welcome, thanks..

Comment: By orthogonal operator you mean orthogonal projection?

Comment: No, I mean $TT^*=T^*T=I$, i.e., $T^*$ is the inverse of $T$..

Comment: OK. This is also called a normal operator.

Comment: @user99680 how you know that this operator have eigen values?? This is true ever in $\mathbb{C}$ not in $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: @LuisValerin This is not called a normal operator...it is called an orthogonal operator. Normal means $T^*$ and $T$ commute.

Comment: @LuisValerin, yes, my bad, I deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Eric yes you right, rather is called unitary operator.

Comment: @LuisValerin "Unitary" is the standard term in a complex vector space. "Orthogonal" is the standard term in a real vector space.

Comment: It's not much, but I think the point of the hint is to note that $T+T^*$ is symmetric, so that $T + T^*$ has a one dimensional invariant subspace $W$ and somehow proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to even use the assumption that $T$ is orthogonal. In fact, $T$ being orthogonal allows us to conclude a much stronger conclusion:

There exists a collection of *mutually orthogonal* $T$-subspaces $\{W_1,\ W_2,\ \cdots,\ W_k\}$ each of which has dimension $1$ or $2$ and together
$$\mathbb{R}^n = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$$
This essentially says that orthogonal operators are generalized (improper) rotations.

Anyways, back to the question at hand, we can prove the following.

**Theorem**: Let $A$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $A$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ or $2$.

**Proof**: Suppose $A$ has a real eigenvalue. Then $A$ has a real eigenvector which trivially spans an invariant subspace of dimension $1$. In particular, we see that this holds for odd $n$.

Now suppose that $\lambda = \lambda_1 + i\lambda_2$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$ with $\lambda_1,\ \lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_1 + i\mathbf{v}_2$ be the corresponding eigenvector.

Then we have
$$\begin{align}\lambda\mathbf{v} = (\lambda_1 + i\lambda_2)(\mathbf{v}_1 + i\mathbf{v}_2) &= (\lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1 - \lambda_2\mathbf{v}_2) + i(\lambda_1\mathbf{v}_2 + \lambda_2\mathbf{v}_1)
\\&=A\mathbf{v}_1 + iA\mathbf{v}_2 = A\mathbf{v}\end{align}$$
Equating real and imaginary parts, we have
$$A\mathbf{v}_1 = \lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1 - \lambda_2\mathbf{v}_2$$
$$A\mathbf{v}_2 = \lambda_1\mathbf{v}_2 + \lambda_2\mathbf{v}_1$$
Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ \mathbf{v}_2\}$. Then it follows that 
$$A(c_1\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2\mathbf{v}_2) = (c_1\lambda_1 + c_2\lambda_2)\mathbf{v}_1 + (c_2\lambda_1 - c_1\lambda_2)\mathbf{v}_2$$

Therefore $W$ is $A$ invariant. $\square$

Comment: +1. You said succinctly what I was struggling to formulate.